# BeautifulSoup: when pulling text from a section, <emph> and other tags are ignored causing adjacent words to be pushed together

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, parsing, beautifulsoup

I have an XML document. I want to pull all text between all

.. <.p> tags. Below is an example of the text. The problem is that in a sentence like:

```
"Because the <emph>raspberry</emph> and.."
```

the output is "Because theraspberryand...". Somehow, the emph tags are being dropped (which is good) but being dropped in a way that pushes together the adjacent word.

Here is the relevant code I am using:

```
xml = BeautifulSoup(xml, convertEntities=BeautifulSoup.HTML_ENTITIES)
for para in xml.findAll('p'):
    text = text + " " + para.text + " "
```

Here is a the start of part of the text, in case the full text helps:

```
<!DOCTYPE art SYSTEM "keton.dtd">
<art jid="PNAS" aid="1436" vid="94" iss="14" date="07-08-1997" ppf="7349" ppl="7355">
<fm>
<doctopic>Developmental Biology</doctopic>
<dochead>Inaugural Article</dochead>
<docsubj>Biological Sciences</docsubj>
<atl>Suspensor-derived polyembryony caused by altered expression of
valyl-tRNA synthetase in the <emph>twn2</emph>
mutant of <emph>Arabidopsis</emph></atl>
<prs>This contribution is part of the special series of Inaugural
Articles by members of the National Academy of Sciences elected on
April 30, 1996.</prs>
<aug>
<au><fnm>James Z.</fnm><snm>Zhang</snm></au>
<au><fnm>Chris R.</fnm><snm>Somerville</snm></au>
<fnr rid="FN150"><aff>Department of Plant Biology, Carnegie Institution of Washington,
290 Panama Street, Stanford CA 94305</aff>
</fnr></aug>
<acc>May 9, 1997</acc>
<con>Chris R. Somerville</con>
<pubfront>
<cpyrt><date><year>1997</year></date>
<cpyrtnme><collab>The National Academy of Sciences of the USA</collab></cpyrtnme></cpyrt>
<issn>0027-8424</issn><extent>7</extent><price>2.00/0</price>
</pubfront>
<fn id="FN150"><p>To whom reprint requests should be addressed. e-mail:
<email>crs@andrew.stanford.edu</email>.</p>
</fn>
<abs><p>The <emph>twn2</emph> mutant of <emph>Arabidopsis</emph>
exhibits a defect in early embryogenesis where, following one or two
divisions of the zygote, the decendents of the apical cell arrest. The
basal cells that normally give rise to the suspensor proliferate
abnormally, giving rise to multiple embryos. A high proportion of the
seeds fail to develop viable embryos, and those that do, contain a high
proportion of partially or completely duplicated embryos. The adult
plants are smaller and less vigorous than the wild type and have a
severely stunted root. The <emph>twn2-1</emph> mutation, which is the
only known allele, was caused by a T-DNA insertion in the 5′
untranslated region of a putative valyl-tRNA synthetase gene,
<it>valRS</it>. The insertion causes reduced transcription of the
<it>valRS</it> gene in reproductive tissues and developing seeds but
increased expression in leaves. Analysis of transcript initiation sites
and the expression of promoter–reporter fusions in transgenic plants
indicated that enhancer elements inside the first two introns interact
with the border of the T-DNA to cause the altered pattern of expression
of the <it>valRS</it> gene in the <emph>twn2</emph> mutant. The
phenotypic consequences of this unique mutation are interpreted in the
context of a model, suggested by Vernon and Meinke &amp;lsqbVernon, D. M. &amp;
Meinke, D. W. (1994) <emph>Dev. Biol.</emph> 165, 566–573&amp;rsqb, in
which the apical cell and its decendents normally suppress the
embryogenic potential of the basal cell and its decendents during early
embryo development.</p>
</abs>
</fm>
```

Comment: What version of BeautifulSoup are you using? And with what parser (and, if lxml, which lxml and libxml2 versions)? Because when I try this, I get "The twn2 mutant…", with spaces.

Comment: Wait a sec… you're using `HTML_ENTITIES`. That doesn't exist in bs4. So, if you're just noticing that bs3 has some issues and you want to know how to deal with that, the answer is almost always to use bs4. Hence the big red warning at the top of the [BS3 docs](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs3/documentation.html).

Comment: Currently using 3.2.1. Do you know of any easy fix with bs3? I mean, I can install bs4, there's just a decent cost to it... doing this on AWS (spark), so have to SSH into each computer (9 of them) and install it.. .

Comment: Scratch that! Using "from bs4 import BeautifulSoup" worked just fine. Thanks!

Comment: While we're at it, you should probably be specifying `xml` (bs4) or using `BeautifulStoneSoup` (bs3) instead of asking it to parse your XML as slightly defective HTML. Also, instead of looping over `text = text + " " + para.text + " "`, why not just loop over `paras.append(para.text)` and then do one big `text += ' '.join(paras)` at the end?

Comment: Are you using BeautifulSoup because your XML is malformed... or is it just because you've not got an `</art>` at the end here? (ie, have you mis-pasted or is it genuinely mal-formed?)

Comment: There are about 15,000 XML documents in the corpus. Unfortunately, some of them are malformed. To stop it from breaking on any one malformed on, I'm just using BeautifulSoup. Messy, but seems to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem here is that you're trying to write bs4 code with bs3.

The obvious fix is to the use bs4 instead.

But in bs3, the docs show two ways to get all of the text recursively from all contents of a soup:

```
''.join(e for e in soup.recursiveChildGenerator() if isinstance(e, unicode))
''.join(soup.findAll(text=True))
```

You can obviously change either one of those to explicitly strip whitespace off the edges and add exactly one space between each node instead of relying on whatever space might be there:

```
' '.join(e.strip() for e in soup.recursiveChildGenerator() if isinstance(e, unicode))
' '.join(map(str.strip, soup.findAll(text=True)))
```

I wouldn't want to guarantee that this will be exactly the same as the bs4 `text` property… but I think it's what you want here.